# Writing out umlaut chars in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, utf-8

I need to write the "&#D;" equivalent of a umlaut char to an xml.
Example if the string is "für" then the expected output is "`f&#252;r`" the  `&#252;` being the equivalent of ü

Here is the code I currently have:

```
private bool WriteOutXMLFile(string xsltFileName, XsltArgumentList argsList, string outputFile)
    {

            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
            transform.Load(xsltFileName);

            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile,false,Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                transform.Transform(this.InputFilePath, argsList, sw);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:param name="InsideSales1"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="InsideSales2"></xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <!--Project output nodes-->
 <!--Calculation Number-->
 <xsl:template match="kalkulationsnummer" >
 <xsl:element name="kalkulationsnummer">
  <xsl:value-of select="$CalculationNumber" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have remove a lot of params for space considerations.

Can someone help?

Regards.

Hello everyone,
I have used 
    System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
method to get the required value for umlaut chars when adding them to the argsList. This was a quicker way of doing things but it may not work as it is not tested for my requirement.
a better approach would be to use a byte array, suggested in this post.
Thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: Why do you think you need a numeric character reference like `&#252;` instead of the plain character `ü` in an UTF-8 encoded file? If you wanted `US-ASCII` as the encoding a character reference makes sense but with Unicode I don't see any reason to want that.

Comment: Well, the client wants it that way, either the program on his end can't read or he cant program it to read the ü. I don't have a choice, if you understand Martin!

Comment: The client should learn to use an XML library, then. Using XML should be totally transparent about encoding, this is one of the key points about XML in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:output encoding="us-ascii"/>
```

In your C# code try:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile,false,Encoding.ASCII))
```

Comment: Tried, does not work. It outputs the '?' for the umlaut char.

Comment: @Codehelp: Are you sure you have `Encoding.ASCII` in your code? If so, you need to check the result stream and verify that whether it contains `'?'` characters or the wanted character entities. If the `'?'` characters are already there, you would have to write your own XmlWriter and pass it as a parameter to the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

First, use us-ascii as the xsl:output encoding, as suggested by Dimitre. Second, send the transformation output to a byte stream destination, not a character stream destination. If you use a character stream destination (a Writer), the XSLT processor will not be encoding characters as bytes, it will leave that to the Writer, and the Writer doesn't know anything about XML or how XML likes to escape unencodable characters.